# FFmpeg remove every 6th frame starting from the 3rd frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have several 30fps videos to convert to videos with acceptable resolution and framerate for a DVD using this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe" -i "INPUT.MP4" -vf "select='mod(n,6)',crop=720:576:x=280:y=72" -r 25 -metadata:s:v:0 language= -metadata:s:a:0 language= -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 "OUTPUT.MKV"
```

This does mostly what I anticipate. However, I want the command to select frames to remove using this arithmetic sequence: 6x-3 (3, 9, 15, 21, etc.). I experimented with the modulus function, however, I couldn't achieve the desired result.

I am not at all very experienced with FFmpeg, and I want to avoid having to extract frames from the video, remove the frames and re-encode the video.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Are you sure it's even *true* 30fps? US drop-frame would actually be 29.997. I'd be looking for some kind of pre-made filter "NTSC > PAL" [because the colours won't be the same either] though most 'DVD' players these days can do that on the fly

Comment: The videos are truly 30fps, I checked with ffprobe and calculated with total frames / total duration in seconds.

Comment: What happens if one of your pseudo-randomly-chosen frames is a keyframe?

Comment: I completely misunderstood you, Ignore my other comment. There is a keyframe every 16 frames. Taking out every 6th starting from the 3rd frame shouldn't take out any I-frames. But do I have to re-encode P-frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing every 6'th frame starting from the third frame, we may use:

```
select='mod(n+4,6)'
```

The frames counting starts from zero, and when mod(n+4,6) = 0, the frame is not selected.

- `mod(0+4,6) = 4`  - first frame is selected.
- `mod(1+4,6) = 5`  - second frame is selected.
- `mod(2+4,6) = 0`  - third frame is not selected.

---

Using `-r 25` as output argument, duplicates frames.
Instead of `-r 25` as output, we may use `-vsync 0` (passthrough) and [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filter for correcting the timestamps. We may also add `-r 25` as input argument for correcting the frame period:

`ffmpeg -y -r 25 -vsync 0 -i test.mp4 -vf "select='mod(n+4,6)',setpts='N/25/TB'" "OUTPUT.MKV"`

---

Testing:

Build 30fps synthetic video with running counter:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=60 -vf setpts=N/TB/30 test.mp4
```

Removing every 6'th frame starting from the third, and converting to 25fps:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -vsync 0 -i test.mp4 -vf "select='mod(n+4,6)',setpts='N/25/TB'" "OUTPUT.MKV"
```

Convert to sequence of PNG images (for testing):

```
ffmpeg -i OUTPUT.MKV %04d.png
```

Output frames:
[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]

We can see that frames 2 and 8 are missing.

We may also verify that the framerate is 25fps using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) tool:

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Duration                                 : 2 s 0 ms
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted, however, I have one more enquiry about this answer. The original video has a total duration of 167s and 900ms, however, the command outputs a file with a total duration of 167s and 880ms. Is it possible to retain the duration of the original file?

Comment: Never mind, the 1st frame was duplicated and even though it was removed, it caused unexpected behaviour with the modulo function. Now that I know that it actually return the remainder, I can fix that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`shuffleframes`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#shuffleframes):

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -vf "**shuffleframes**=0 1 -1 2 3 4", setpts=N/(25*TB) -r 25 OUTPUT.mp4
```

The `-1` index in the third place instructs FFmpeg to drop the third frame.